# Sed - remove all semicolons between a pair of double-quotes

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a dirty csv-file containing rows with quoted semicolons. I am trying to clear these semicolons with commands like:

```
sed -rin 's/(^.*\;.*\;\".*)(\;)(.*\"\;.*$)/\1\3/' file
```

But somehow this doesn't remove all of the semicolons. Some of the problematic rows look like this:

```
;0;"One ▒;)";123; ... ; nth-1column;
;0;"Two ▒;)";456; ... ; nthcolumn;
```

When they should be cleaned to:

```
;0;"One ▒)";123; ... ; nth-1column;
;0;"Two ▒)";456; ... ; nthcolumn;
```

There might be some encoding issues, but this should be ignored by the regex. I am only interested in removing the semicolons, the encoding is handled afterwards.

Any ideas on how to aggressively clean all semicolons contained within double-quotes?

Comment: The semicolons in double quotes are valid in CSV, why do you need to remove them?

Comment: They cannot be handled by the tool I am reading the file into, so unfortunately the fastest solution is to remove them

Comment: `sed ':a;s/^\(\([^"]*;\?\|"[^";]*";\?\)*"[^";]*\);/\1/;ta' file`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question instead of writing comments to answer. Do the quoted semicolons occur in the third column only or in more than one column? Are the same columns quoted in all rows? The behavior of `sed` may depend on your locale, especially when you have wrong encoding. Try `LANG=C sed ...`. Instead of `^.*\;.*\;` you may need `^[^;]*\;[^;]*\;` because `.` also matches `;` or `"`. Depending on the later columns your `sed` command may remove a wrong semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^;"]*"[^"]*)*"[^";]*);/\1/;ta' file
```

Make a back reference starting from the front of each line that contain characters not between double quotes and quoted strings that do not contain `;`'s followed by double quote and characters that are neither double-quote or semi-colon. If the next character is a semi-colon, remove it and repeat until failure, then print the result.

An alternative:

```
sed -E '/^([^"]*("[^";]*"[^"]*)*"[^";]*);/{s//\n\1/;D}' file
```

or:

```
sed -E 's/^([^"]*("[^";]*"[^"]*)*"[^";]*);/\n\1/;T;D' file
```

EDIT:

```
sed -nE '/^([^"]*("[^";]*"[^"]*)*"[^";]*);/{:a;s//\1/;ta;p}' file
```

Comment: Great! I will give it a try. Can the output be silenced with sed -nE?

Comment: @bullfighter if you activate the -n option you will get no output. If you only want to ouput lines that have been changed then see edit. If you want to edit the file in place use the -i option

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed ':a;s/^\(\([^"]*;\?\|"[^";]*";\?\)*"[^";]*\);/\1/;ta' file
```

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/Q7wZ6h).

It works like this:

- `:a` - sets `a` label
- `^\(\([^"]*;\?\|"[^";]*";\?\)*"[^";]*\);` - find:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\(\([^"]*;\?\|"[^";]*";\?\)*"[^";]*\)` - Group 1:

    - `\([^"]*;\?\|"[^";]*";\?\)*` - zero or more occurrences of

      - `[^"]*;\?` - zero or more chars other than `"` and then an optional `;`
      - `\|` - or
      - `"[^";]*";\?` - `"`, then zero or more chars other than `"` and `;` and then a `"` and then an optional `;`
    - `"` - a `"` char
    - `[^";]*` - zero or more chars other than a `;` and `"`
  - `;`  -  a semi-colon
- `\1` - replace with Group 1 value
- `ta` - if there was a substitution, go back to `a` label position.